# Dynamic array creation (bound to a grid) based on a user entered number in the UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have employee information being entered in an angular application.

Got a input type=number that accepts a number (let's say number of employees). As the user enters a number for ex: 3, Dynamically the UI needs to populate a table of 3 rows in the UI (We will need to ng-repeat on the numberOfEmployees here obviously). Each row should be bound to an employee object with names.

So, my json object that is bound to UI looks like this,

```
{
  numberOfEmployees : null,
  "employees" : [
      {
        firstName: "set from view",
        lastName: "set from view",
        amount: "set from view"
      },
      {
        firstName: "set from view",
        lastName: "set from view",
        amount: "set from view"
      }
    ]
}
```

input type=number in the view should be bound to **numberOfEmployees**. 
The grid should be bound to the **employees** array.

I think I will have to setup a watch on the numberOfEmployees and do a push, splice in to the employees array. But the logic becomes wonky too quickly, when you think about things like,

1. User enters 2 as the number, fills in the data in the employees grid, then goes back up and changes the number to 3 or 1, now you'll need to adjust the array every time the number changes, figuring out which array item to remove and where to add new one etc.

**How to solve this elegantly in an angular prescribed way?**

Answer (score 1):

How constrained are you in your design? Typically when i'm approaching a form that needs to dynamically grow I add a "add employee" button. It adds a row each time its clicked. By making the change in the grid more granular you reduce complexity.

**Current UI:**

Assuming you're stuck with your UI, you could indeed use a `$scope.$watch` in your controller.

You could also attach a handler to the input itself with `ng-change="updateEmployees()"`

Template:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="numOfEmployees">
<table ng-controller="EmployeesCtrl">
  <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="employee.firstName"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="employee.lastName"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="employee.amount"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('curExample')

.controller('EmployeesCtrl', function () {

  $scope.employees = [];
  $scope.numOfEmployees = 0;

  $scope.addEmployee = function() {
    $scope.employees.push({
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      amount: ""
    });
  };


  $scope.removeEmployees = function(start, count) {
    if (start > -1) {
      $scope.employees.splice(start, count);
    }
  };

  $scope.updateEmployees = function () {
    var newNum = $scope.numOfEmployees,
        curNum = $scope.employees.length;

    if(!newNum || newNum === curNum) return; 

    if(newNum > curNum) {
      for(var i = 0; i < (newNum - curNum); i++) {
        $scope.addEmployee();
      }
    } else {
      $scope.removeEmployees(curNum - 1, curNum - newNum);
    }
  };

  $scope.$watch('numOfEmployees', function (newValue) {
    $scope.updateEmployees();
  });
});
```

**Alternative UI:**

This solution looks something akin to the following. I'll post a JSFiddle when I have a moment

Template:

```
<table ng-controller="EmployeesCtrl">
  <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="employee.firstName"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="employee.lastName"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="employee.amount"></td>
    <td><button ng-click="removeEmployee($index)">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button ng-click="addEmployee()">Add Employee</button>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('altExample')

.controller('EmployeesCtrl', function () {

  $scope.employees = [];

  $scope.addEmployee = function() {
    $scope.employees.push({
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      amount: ""
    });
  };


  $scope.removeEmployee = function(index) {
    if (index > -1) {
      $scope.employees.splice(index, 1);
    }
  };

});
```

Comment: I am very, I mean very constrained with the UI. This is what I am given unfortunately and can't change it. Thanks for answer, your solution would have worked if the UI was different.

Comment: Sorry to hear, I'll adapt my answer to help out.

Comment: Answer updated. Didn't test, but should give an idea of what you could do.